# Как узнать время у пользователя Discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord-api, discord.py

Я тестирую бота в Discord и пытаюсь получить текущее время в часах у пользователя, в каком часовом поясе он находиться не известно.
Естественно `datetime.now()` и `datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))` у пользователя дают одинаковый результат, потому что он показывает время моего запущенного клиента.

Как я могу получить время пользователя?

Comment: Если вы посмотрите [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.User), то заметите, что `User` не хранит никакой информации о часовом поясе или локальном времени, а значит получить эту информацию адекватным путем не получится

Answer (score 2):

Похожий вопрос [уже задавали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876077/how-do-i-get-the-timezone-of-the-message-author-in-my-discord-server-discord-p) на английском stackoverflow, насколько я знаю, с того момента ничего не изменилось.

> Встраивание Discord имеет `timestamp` поле, которое можно установить
> для `datetime` объекта. К сожалению, невозможно определить часовой
> пояс пользователя через API, предоставляемым Discord.
>
> Вы можете просмотреть [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.timestamp) по классу встроенных данных
> discord.py.

Comment: Ещё есть message.created_at, но как я понял он просто выдает время по UTC?

Comment: @ПоляковРоман, да, по UTC

Comment: `embed.set_timestamp` установит таймстамп встраиванию, но никак не поможет помочь получить часовой пояс пользователя. `discord.User` не хранит никакой информации о часовом поясе или локальном времени, и получить её, к сожалению, никак нельзя.